# how to get directories and files list

Tags: apache-2.2, php

I have installed apache-php-mysql on my ununtu 12.10. I kept a directory under /var/www/mydirectory.

There is no index.php in the directory. When I tried to open the directory in browser it is not showing any files or directories in mydirectory.

What changes to be done? 
(apache is running)

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you want Apache to return a directory listing via HTTP then you'll need to use `mod_autoindex` module.

Setting that up is outside the scope of this site; there are plenty of instructions around the web. If you do get stuck on a particular part while setting it up, do feel free to ask a new question.